# Delphi Printing Techniques

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-2009

Where can I find a good resource for adding print capabilities to my program?

I found this page: http://efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Printing/index.html but it hasn't been updated in 5 years, and I'd like to know if, with Delphi 2009, StretchDIBits is still preferred to StretchDrawMap, how to best support pagination, preview, etc.

To date, I've cheated by creating html or pdf documents than printing those, but it is a bit onerous to go this far for all print tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest Fast Report http://fast-report.com/en/ the best Report tool I have used.

I have used QuickReport, Fortes Report, Report Builder and Rave before Fast Report.

Comment: I have found Fast Report to be very good too.

Comment: The question wasn't asking specifically about printing reports.

Answer (score 1):

Creating HTML and PDFs actually doesn't sound that bad.
Printing directly with the supplied API is.

All the answers till now contain report components. There is a good reason - this is the most flexible and powerful way to print.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Rave Reports.

Answer (score 0):

[ReportBuilder Pro](http://www.digital-metaphors.com/) is a very good report generator for adding printing capabilities to your program.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Delphi already come with some printing components? They should be fine for normal use. In older versions it was QuickReport, nowadays it's something else (Rave Report (edited))

Comment: Actual Delphi Versions have Rave Reports.